# box-shadow with scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I am playing with CSS now, i had make a TextArea with box shadow

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 3px black;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 3px black;
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 3px black;
```

and a vertical scroll bar. But the output is a bit bad, the text is overlay the box-shadow. Any idea to solve this?

[image]

thanks to @jiff for jsfiddle, grey box-shadow will be more observe.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/112o9qma/4/)

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong here...

Comment: @TamarG I made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/112o9qma/) to understand. take a look, I think scroll bar is over on box shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Try add padding: 20px; to textarea

Comment: tried, no use, content scroll to top it still overlay

Answer (score 1):

you may see if using a wrapper and a pseudo would fix your issue : https://jsfiddle.net/df7Lhomu/

```css
.tbl {
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  display:table;
}
.tbl:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:2px;
  left:2px;
  right:1.2em;;
  bottom:4px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px 3px black;
  pointer-events:none;
}

textarea{
padding-left:3px;/* box-shadow;*/
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background:#222;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <textarea>
add
some
text
long
enough
in
order
to
see
the
text
behavior
while
scrolling
</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: seem like posible, but i can see a black line block the word as it no stick to the border of textarea

Comment: @YuYenkan the concept is right, you may need to tune it a little to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below css

```
white-space: nowrap;
padding:10px;
```